# Usage of regex function in sql

Tags: sql, hive

| Trackingid |
| --- |
| 00054123 |
| 00054214 |

From the above table, I want to select the trackingid's without the 000 prefix. Currently I am using substring function. Is there a way to do it using regex function? Thanks for your help.

I tried substring it works. I would like to know if this can be accomplished using regex function.

Answer (score 0):

`regexp_replace` is one option, e.g.

```
regexp_replace(trackingid, '^0+', '')
```

saying that it should replace any number `*` of leading `^` zero `0` characters with an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Also it can be done using cast as `int` or `bigint`:

```
cast(Trackingid as int)
```

This method is applicable only when you have integral numbers.
Single character input 0 will be left as is in this case and converted to integer 0